# Gram-Schmidt function not working C++

Tags: c++, arrays, math, linear-algebra

I'm trying to implement a **Gram-Schmidt function in C++**. I have the set of vectors in a 2-dimensional array called `matrix[][]`, and I save the output in a `base[][]` matrix. Every vector is a file of the matrix. Using my class notes, I wrote this code:

```
void gramSchmidt(double matrix[][dim], double base[][dim])
{
    int k,i,j,m;
    double sum;
    double sum1;
    double sum2;
    sum1 = sum2 = 0.0;

    for (i=0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        base[0][i] = matrix[0][i];

    }
    for (k=0; k < dim; k++)
    {
        sum = 0.0;
        for (i=0; i < dim; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j < k-1; j++)
            {
                for (m=0; m < dim; m++)
                {
                    sum1 += base[j][m]*matrix[k][m];
                    sum2 += base[j][m]*base[j][m];

                }
                 sum += sum1/sum2 * base[j][i];
                 cout << sum << endl;
            }
            base[k][i] = matrix[k][i] - sum;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

But it is not working.

Note: I do not want to use `std::vector` or boost or any other C++ specific class. Please try to avoid them in the solution.

**EDIT / Answer to comments**

First of all, this is not homework. I'm making a investigation work for my university. The first objective is diagonalize a quantum mechanics operator. To do that, I decided to do a tridiagonalization with a QR iterated decomposition - that will give me the eigenvalues. As you may know, to do that I need to perform a Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization on my operator.
I don't want to use the std::vector class because arrays provide a easy way to calculate my operator. I'm not working with classes, only with double/int values, so I won't have an huge difference in time (I think).

I'm not going to have a dim-1 array of elements NEVER, because that's the dimension of my space.

I know that this is not working because I proved with a matrix, and it returned the same matrix except the last line. And the resultant vectors are clearly not orthogonal. I did the calculus manually.

Also I'm not requesting a piece of code, not "write the code for me". Any help is appreciated. If you give me a piece of code, it will be great. If you detect an error on my code, it will be great. Also if you give me a link to a good efficient algorithms that fits my data entry, excellent.

*And what happens if k == 0? / You have initialized the first row of b. What about the other rows?* Looks like I'm doing something wrong there. Checking it right now.

**EDIT 2 / SOLUTION**

Thanks to Conor's suggestion about *modified* Gram-Schmidt method, I found this class notes: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-335j-introduction-to-numerical-methods-fall-2010/lecture-notes/MIT18_335JF10_lec10a_hand.pdf which explain the topic and give the modified GS algorithm. I solved the problem using it, looks like it works perfect.

Code:

```
void gramSchmidt(double matrix[][dim], double base[][dim])
{
    int i,j,k;
    double r[dim][dim];
    double v[dim][dim];

    for (i=0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j < dim; j++)
        {
            v[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        r[i][i] = getNorm(v[i]);
        for (j=0; j < dim; j++)
        {
            base[i][j] = v[i][j] / r[i][i];
        }
        for (k=i+1;  k < dim; k++)
        {
            r[i][k] = dotProduct(base[i],v[k]);
            for (j=0; j < dim; j++)
            {
                v[k][j] = v[k][j] - r[i][k] * base[i][j];
            }
        }
    }


    return;
}
```

Comment: Not working? How? Any evidence?

Comment: If you're going to disallow `std::vector` etc, at least use the alternatives right. Kind of sucks if I pass an array of `dim-1` elements.

Comment: `I do NOT want to use std::vector or boost or any other C++ specific class. Please try to avoid them in the solution.` So is the problem your algorithm or your non-usage of these other types you say you can't use? If you don't know, then the simplest way to know what is at issue is to use one of these "unallowed" types and see if your answers come out correct. If they come out correct, then it is your array that is at fault.

Comment: `And better if you give me a very efficient/fast implementation` - that sounds suspiciously like "Please write my code for me". And "no `std::vector`" sounds suspiciously like "please do my homework exercise for me".

Comment: Could you give us sample output and input?

Comment: `for (j=0; j < k-1; j++)`  And what happens if `k == 0`?

Comment: In case you're wondering why you're being downvoted: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have initialized the first row of `b`. What about the other rows?

Comment: I've answered your comments in an edit. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly my advice would be to utilise a vector operation package because it will make your program a lot cleaner, secondly the normal Gram-Schmidt method is not recommended for numerical evaluation due to floating point errors (ref. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#Numerical_stability)).

```
void gramSchmidt()
{
double a[3][3] = {
    {1.0, -1.0, 1.0},
    {1.0, 0.0, 1.0},
    {1.0, 1.0, 2.0}
};

double Result[3][3];
double u1[3],u2[3],u3[3],v1[3],v2[3],v3[3];

for (int i =0; i<3; i++) // Set Result Array to 0 and set the values for u vectors
    for(int j= 0; j<3; j++)
    {
        Result[i][j] = 0.0;

        if (i == 0)
        {
            u1[j] = a[i][j];
        } else if (i == 1)
        {
            u2[j] = a[i][j];
           // std::cout << "u2:" << j << u2[j] << '\n';
        } else if (i == 2)
        {
            u3[j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }

// Solve v1
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
    v1[i] = u1[i];

}


// Solve v2
for (int i=0; i< 3; i++)
{
    v2[i] = u2[i] - func(u2,v1)*v1[i];
}

// Solve v3
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    v3[i] = u3[i] - func(u3, v1)*v1[i] - func(u3, v2)*v2[i];
}

// Normalise 3 vectors and store to Results
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    Result[0][i] = v1[i]*(1/normalise3d(v1));

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    Result[1][i] = v2[i]*(1/normalise3d(v2));
}

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    Result[2][i] = v3[i]*(1/normalise3d(v3));
}




for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    std::cout << '\n';
    for(int j = 0; j<3; j++)
        std::cout << Result[i][j] << ' ';
}
return;
}



double normalise3d (double a[3])
{
double normal = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++)
    normal+= a[i]*a[i];

normal = sqrt(normal);

return normal;
}

double func (double a[3], double b[3]) // To solve proj(w)
{
double ans = 0.0;
double norm = normalise3d(b);

double vecProduct = 0.0;

for (int i= 0; i < 3; i++)
    vecProduct += a[i] * b[i];


ans = vecProduct/(norm * norm);

std::cout << "ans: " << ans << '\n';


return ans;

}
```

Comment: Well, my problem its that the dimension is completely arbitrary, so I can have 5000x5000 matrices... I'll try to adapt your algorithm to fit my code. Also, the search for "modified Gram-Schmidt" gave interesting results. Let me a time to prove this... Thank you!

Comment: Solved using modified GS. Check the edit and thank you again!